# Python Regex longer hyphen and letter before it

Tags: python, regex

I have a DataFrame where some values are stored as "Miami–Fort Lauderdale" and "Minneapolis–Saint Paul" with longer hyphen "–" (not short dash "-"). I am trying to remove them with regex in Windows command prompt, but it's not working properly.

1. directly typing the hyphen as below does not work (werid enough):

```
XXX.replace(to_replace=r'\–', value=' ', regex=True)

XXX.replace(to_replace='–', value=' ')
```

and gives unchanged "Miami–Fort Lauderdale" and "Minneapolis–Saint Paul". Thus, I suppose for some reason cmd does not recognize hyphen.

2. the general form is "lowercase letter + hyphen + uppercase letter" so I also tried

```
XXX.replace(to_replace=r'(?=[a-z]+)\W(?=[A-Z]+)', value=' ', regex=True)
```

interestingly this gives unchanged "Miami–Fort Lauderdale" and "Minneapolis–Saint Paul"

3. however, the following will work

```
XXX.replace(to_replace=r'\W(?=[A-Z]+)', value=' ', regex=True)
```

and gives desired "Miami Fort Lauderdale" and "Minneapolis Saint Paul". But the problem is that this messes up other values like "Washington, D.C." into "Washington, D C." (apparently).

=====================================================

I eventually solved this by

```
XXX.replace(to_replace=r'\W(?=\w+\s)', value=' ', regex=True)
```

but I still wonder how Regex recognizes the letter before hyphen "–". It appears to me as if for some reason, a letter right before hyphen is not considered as a letter?

Comment: Is it Python 2 or 3? You have an en-dash here, and it seems working fine, no need to escape it BTW. Also, did you maybe miss `inplace=True`? As for the regex in Point 2, you just made a typo by using a lookahead at the start, it must be a lookbehind, `r'(?<=[a-z])\W(?=[A-Z])`.

Comment: Though, I'd rather use ``r'(?<=[a-z])[^\w\s](?=[A-Z])`` to exclude whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Im using Python 3.7.9. Good point but no, this is not about inplace. With or without it was not working for me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the content of your post. But I can remember that unicode comes with a bunch or close characters: `-` or HYPHEN-MINUS (U+002D), `–` or EN DASH (U+2013) and `—` or EM DASH (U+2014). Maybe there are others. Make sure to use the right one...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ```.replace(to_replace=r'(?<=[a-z])[^\w\s](?=[A-Z])', value=' ', regex=True)``` works perfectly. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
.replace(to_replace=r'(?<=[a-z])[^\w\s](?=[A-Z])', value=' ', regex=True)
```

Here,

- `(?<=[a-z])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with a lowercase ASCII letter
- `[^\w\s]` - a char other than a word and whitespace char
- `(?=[A-Z])`- a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with an uppercase ASCII letter.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/50MDrI/2).

Also, note that `\w` matches an underscore, that is also a punctuation symbol. If you ever need to "include" it here, you will need an alternation:

```py
(?<=[a-z])(?:[^\w\s]|_)(?=[A-Z])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me whether you are using regular Python, Pandas, or something else.  One possible issue you might be having is that you never declared your Python script to be using UTF-8 characters.  Consider the following working example:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

inp = "Miami–Fort Lauderdale"
output = re.sub(r'–', ' ', inp)
print(inp + "\n" + output)
```

This prints (as expected):

```
Miami–Fort Lauderdale
Miami Fort Lauderdale
```

Comment: This is super weird:
1. when I directly copy paste your code into windows cmd, hyphen turns into dash 
2. otherwise, this works perfect when not inside a dataframe

Comment: ...which could also be a manifestation of an issue with the character set you are using (perhaps `cmd` doesn't support one or other of the characters).

Comment: Thanks! this is also an important direction. I should consider using a different platform